# How to access lock sentinel redis access privacy for multiple pods?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, redis

I have a redis sentinel 1 master and 2 slave. And I have deployed a web dotnet core web api application 3 pods on cluster. So each pod has a background worker that access to file system, does own work and update redis with a key (done=true). Each pod runs same worker.

So if done=false each pods runs same time for same job. So I want to run first accessed pod do the job, others not to do. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add another key to Redis that becomes a lock mechanism with pod ID or something. So if `done = true` then `locked = false`. When `done = false` the first pod that gets the information and succeeds to set `locked` can start the file system job. When the job is finished, the pod updates `done = true` and `locked = false`.

To avoid race conditions you must use [transactions](https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/) where you `WATCH` a value when updating it. If the watched value gets updated the transaction will fail.

Pseudocode:

```
WATCH locked
res = GET locked
IF res == false
  MULTI
  SET locked pod123
  EXEC
```

You also need to handle the scenario when a pod goes down and the lock stays in `locked = pod123`.